# Finding $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I did

$$\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx = [x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{2}*\arcsin(x)]^1_{-1} = \\
\frac{1}{2}[\arcsin(1)-\arcsin(-1)] = \frac{1}{2}[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{3\pi}{2}] = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I'm trying to calculate an area with this and obviously an area can't be negative. What went wrong?

Comment: Generally arcsin is defined so that $\arcsin(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$, not $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\arcsin(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$, not $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$; remember where the $\sin$ is invertible.

Comment: But why though?

Comment: When you want to define an inverse you need to restrict the domain and the image of a function such that it is bijective in that restriction; it was chosen, by convention, to restrict the domain of $\sin$ to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.